# Converting a Future[T] to an always-successful Future[Option[T]]

Tags: web-services, scala, playframework, future, playframework-2.3

The motivating use-case I have in mind is as follows:

- In a Play Framework controller, I am calling Play's `WS`. This produces a potentially-failing `Future`
- I want to handle the separate cases of the `WS` request succeeding vs failing. In both cases, I want to produce a Play `Response` eventually (likely a `Future[Response]`)

What I think I am trying to do is:

- Asynchronously, after the future completes, unconditionally handle the completion
- Produce a `Future[Response]` corresponding to the desired response

I don't believe I can use `Future.map` because I need to customize the handling of the failure case and not just pass on the `Future`'s failure.

If you have any alternative suggestions for how to solve this cleanly, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `Future.recover`.

```
val wsResponse: Future[WSResponse] = ???

wsResponse map { response =>
  // Success case
  Ok(response.json)
} recover {
  // Failure case, turn your throwable into a response
  case t: Throwable =>
    InternalServerError(t.getMessage)
}
```

`recover` takes a partial function `Throwable => T`.  In this case, `T` will probably be an `Option[Response]` so you can construct that according to whatever your business logic is in both the success and fail cases.

Do note that Play's WS library will return a successful future for a failed HTTP call, if (e.g.,) your call returns a 404 from the external server, so your `map` function will still need some error handling.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for pointing out a more standard way of thinking about the problem.